# SQLAlchemy 3.2 and MS SQL Connectivity

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm currently working on a proof of concept application using Python 3.2 via SQLAlchemy with a MS SQL Server back end.  Thus far, I'm hitting a brick wall looking for ways to actually do the connection.  Most discussions point to using pyODBC, however it does not support Python 3.x yet.

Does anyone have any connection examples for MS SQL and SQLAlchemy, under Python 3.2?

This is under Windows 7 64bit also.

Thanks.

Comment: SQLAlchemy 3.2 not exist, perhaps you're referring to the python version you're using, the current SQLAlchemy version it's 0.7. In order to use SQLAlchemy with some database vendor you need three things (at least) to work together python, the db driver and sql alchemy dialect with that driver. In my case python 2.7 psycopg2 (driver for postgresql) and sqlalchemy 0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment none of the known Python drivers to connect to Sql Server had a compatible python 3000 version.

- PyODBC
- mxODBC
- pymssql
- zxjdbc
- AdoDBAPI

Comment: The adodbapi readme says "Fully implemented in Python. -- runs in Python 2.3+ Python 3.0+ and IronPython 2.6+"

Comment: The problem there could be the dialect: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.adodbapi

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I basically scrapped MSSQL and went with MySQL. Only took me a couple hours to rebuild my sql scripts and set my tables up in MySQL.  I'm using the MySQL Connector with SQLAllchemy and was able to throw together a quick connection script and populate a dictionary with results from one of the tables.  

Now to populate a graphic grid.  Once I've done that, and have proved to myself that it can be done, then it's on to the real work - a full Windows based UI desktop application.